# Gatsby, how to do "join" with graphql?

Tags: graphql, gatsby, netlify-cms

I use gatsby and netlify-cms.
My schema:

```
collections:
  - name: "tags"
    label: "Tags"
    folder: "src/data/tags"
    create: true
    slug: "{{slug}}"
    fields: 
      - {label: "Id", name: "title", widget: "string"}
      - {label: "Description", name: "description", widget: "text"}
  - name: "posts"
    label: "Posts"
    folder: "src/data/posts"
    create: true
    slug: "{{slug}}"
    fields:
      - {label: "Id", name: "title", widget: "string"}
      - label: "Tags"
        name: "tags"
        widget: "list"
        fields:
          - label: "Tag"
            name: "tag"
            widget: "relation"
            collection: "tags"
            searchFields: ["name", "description"]
            valueField: "title"
            displayFields: ["name"]
```

My query:

```
query PostByID($id: String!) {
    markdownRemark(id: { eq: $id }) {
      id
      html
      frontmatter {
        id: title
        description
        tags {
            tag
            // get tag description????
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

Is there a way to get tag description? I'm trying to use fragments, but it doesn't work. I asked this question as issue on Gatsby GitHub, I was advised this example:

```
fragment tagDetails on Tag {
  title
  description
}
```

and with this usage:

```
            tag {
              ...tagDetails
            }
```

I get this error: 
"Field \"tag\" must not have a selection since type \"String\" has no subfields."

Comment: I came across your question while trying to solve a similar problem. I assume you have solved it by now, but for the benefit of others I got a little further along with a similar issue by adding node mappings: https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/schema-gql-type/#mapping-field